# MS SQL Studio 2008 - Select SubQuery using SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Having an issue with this sub query using SUM.  The query will be totaling the profit column of several records from a specific date range.  I am grouping this total profit by the account number attached to the record.  With one account number, it works just fine:

```
select
    [ACCOUNT ID],
    (
     select SUM(PROFIT)
     from [Transaction Table]
     where [ACCOUNT ID] in ('1001')
     and [ACTIVITY DATE] in ('5/31/2012')
    ) as 'May Profit'

from
    [Transaction Table]

where
    [ACCOUNT ID] in ('1001')

group by
    [ACCOUNT ID]
```

Gives correct results:

```
    | ACCOUNT ID | May Profit |
    ---------------------------
    |    1001    |   $61.97   |
```

The trouble comes with multiple account numbers:

```
select
    [ACCOUNT ID],
    (
     select SUM(PROFIT)
     from [Transaction Table]
     where [ACCOUNT ID] in ('1001','2001')
     and [ACTIVITY DATE] in ('5/31/2012')
    ) as 'May Profit'

from
    [Transaction Table]

where
    [ACCOUNT ID] in ('1001','2001')

group by
    [ACCOUNT ID]
```

Gives incorrect results:

```
    | ACCOUNT ID | May Profit |
    ---------------------------
    |    1001    |  $127.34   |
    |    2001    |  $127.34   |
```

The "May Profit" is being totaled for both accounts on each record.  I need individual profit totals per account number.

Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use a SubQuery, but here are 2 ways you can do it:

The first way, using your query (not recommended) - Notice the Account Id = T.Account Id:

```
select
    [ACCOUNT ID],
    (
     select SUM(PROFIT)
     from [Transaction Table]
     where [ACCOUNT ID] = T.[ACCOUNT ID]
     and [ACTIVITY DATE] in ('5/31/2012')
    ) as 'May Profit'
from
    [Transaction Table] T
where
    [ACCOUNT ID] in ('1001','2001')
group by
    [ACCOUNT ID]
```

A better way:

```
select
     [ACCOUNT ID],
     SUM(PROFIT)
from [Transaction Table]
where [ACCOUNT ID] in ('1001','2001') and [ACTIVITY DATE] in ('5/31/2012')
group by [ACCOUNT ID]
```

Comment: Your the best Jason!  I was being incomplete on my original question.

Comment: The reason your more clean answer will not work for me.  I need multiple months worth of profit listed on one spread sheet.

Comment: Because of that I am using multiple sub selects to pull, "May Profit", "June Profit", "July Profit" etc.  Could you explain to me why adding the `[ACCOUNT ID] = t.[ACCOUNT ID]` made the difference?

Comment: Because your initial query is coming from [Transaction Table] outside of the sub query, that is where the Account ID's are located. So you are mapping the Account ID from the results of that table, to the sub query where clause, which enables it to only query the result for the specific id in the rows.

Comment: Your a life saver!  I have 10 sub queries all querying the profit column for different date ranges now.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to use subquery

```
 select
     [ACCOUNT ID],
     SUM(PROFIT)
 from [Transaction Table]
 where [ACCOUNT ID] in ('1001','2001') and [ACTIVITY DATE] in ('5/31/2012')
 group by [ACCOUNT ID]
```

your query just counted sum for two accounts and showed it in each row

**update:**

Actually for multiple sums I'd do something like this

```
 select
     [ACCOUNT ID],
     SUM(case when [ACTIVITY DATE] in ('5/31/2012') then PROFIT else 0 end) as 'May Profit',
     SUM(case when [ACTIVITY DATE] in ('4/31/2012') then PROFIT else 0 end) as 'April Profit'
 from [Transaction Table]
 where [ACCOUNT ID] in ('1001','2001') and 
 group by [ACCOUNT ID]
```

Comment: This answer is completely correct too.   If you need to have multiple sub selects in the same query, see Jason Heine's first answer.

Comment: @tcshain added suggested syntax for multiple sums :) I don't really like subselects and they're slower than just one select with aggregates

Comment: If I am understanding these aggregates correctly, you've done a `SUM` on `PROFIT` when `[ACTIVITY DATE]` is met.  Could you explain what the `else 0 end` portion is doing?

Comment: sum is aggregate function, for each row you get a value which equals `PROFIT` if `[ACTIVITY DATE] in ('5/31/2012')` and 0 otherwise and then you sum the values